# How do I get a tiny subset of a image dataset with only a few classes?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to test my custom CNN model, so I want to train my model on a tiny subset and see if it can overfit.My question is as follows: How can I get only a few classes(say 5) for training?

- Here's my dataloader:

```
train_data = CUB200.CUB200(transform=transform_train, train=True)
test_data = CUB200.CUB200(transform=transform_test, train=False)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, drop_last=True)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
```

- custom data:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.datasets.folder import default_loader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset


base_folder = '../../data/CUB_200_2011/'

class CUB200(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, base_folder=base_folder, transform=None, train=True):
        self.base_folder = base_folder
        self.transform = transform
        self.train = train
        images = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_folder, 'images.txt'), sep=' ',
                        names=['img_id', 'filepath'])
        image_class_labels = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_folder, 'image_class_labels.txt'),
                                    sep=' ', names=['img_id', 'target'])
        train_test_split = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_folder, 'train_test_split.txt'),
                                        sep=' ', names=['img_id', 'is_training_img'])
        data = images.merge(image_class_labels, on='img_id')
        data = data.merge(train_test_split, on='img_id')
        if self.train:
            self.data = data[data.is_training_img == 1]
        else:
            self.data = data[data.is_training_img == 0]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sample = self.data.iloc[index]
        path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'images', sample.filepath)
        img = default_loader(path)
        # Target start from 1 in data, so shift to 0
        label = sample.target - 1
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        return img, label
```

- image folder:

[image]

I know we can use `torch.utils.data.Subset` in pytorch for doing this. But if I do this way, I must count the indices of the first 5 classes. Is there any more convient way to do this?

Comment: You are already writing a custom dataset Class, try loading only the classes you want by sending a list, for example, to instantiate the class and load images only from the list. In your case, it can be done by getting a sub-dataframe image_class_labels_sub = (image_class_labels["target"] in your class list) then use img ids from this subest to load images in train test split.

Comment: Good idea!Thanks for the comment. But is there any way without modifing my Class?

Comment: I think this can help in that case - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-one-class-of-number-in-mnist/26276/12?u=pranaymodukuru

Comment: Thank again for your response,it's also a good way.

Comment: https://binitai.github.io/BetterLoader/ - we built BetterLoader to do just this :) [shameless self promo, but I think you may find this helpful if you're tackling a problem like this regularly]